# Freeradius error - Unknown module "X-Ascend-Session-Svr-Key"

Tags: accounting, freeradius

I am using FreeRadius 2.1.12 on Ubuntu Server 14.04 (installed through apt directly from the OS apt repos).

I am getting the following error on every accounting request:

```
WARNING: Unknown module "X-Ascend-Session-Svr-Key" in string expansion "%')"
```

This causes an SQL error when inserting the accounting records into the database.
I have tracked this to dialup.conf accounting_start_query where it tries to insert '%{X-Ascend-Session-Svr-Key}'.

My searches turned out very little on why this could happen.

How can I solve this issue, or debug it to find out why its happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X-Ascend-Session-Srv-Key has not been defined in the dictionaries.  It may have been removed due to compatibility issues, I know Ascend overloaded some of the standards attribute space with their own VSAs (that weren't VSAs).

It's safe to modify the default queries and remove the X-Ascend-Session-Srv-Key references.  That column has been stripped from the default SQL queries and schemas in >= 3.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I removed it from accounting_start_query and accounting_update_query_alt and accounting works correctly.